# Excel data source reference is not valid

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivot from a range but keep getting the error `Data source reference is not valid`

I have Googled this and tried all of the following.

- Select from Table instead from range.
- Open the Excel spreadsheet click on the view tab and select new window. Save the spreadsheet with a different name for the new window.
- Click on HOME> PREPARE> INSPECT DOCUMENT> Removed all unneccesary references and xml forms.

I have labels on all the columns and all the cells are populated.

I am using Office 2010 on Win7 and the file is in .xlsx format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the reason the pivot tables didn't work was because of the file name. The reports are generated by a report automation system and the name contains square brackets `[]` that Excel doesn't like.

I removed the square brackets totally by chance and found the pivots are working.

I also tried to save the file in the `Save As` option with square brackets but like I said, Excel moans about it and doesn't allow you.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same error but didn't have brackets `[]` in my file name. I found that the Excel file from my web-based reporting tool was not actually in XLSX format. When I did a "Save As" in Excel the file type was "**Web page**". I changed that to "**Excel workbook (*.xlsx)**" and saved with the same name and the Pivot Table worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  No brackets in the file name though.  It did however contain a comma "," in the file name and since it was sync'd with OneDrive the ccomma was converted to an "^J" so that could have been the issue too.
I coppied the data to a blank spreadsheet and the pivot table worked fine.  So it told me that there must be an issue with the file name too.  I changed the file name to remove the comma and boom, it worked fine.